# Can't Sort data from an array. sort is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to sort the data from an array, from the minor to the largest one. and I get the error: `time.sort` is not a function, `time.sort` is `undefined`.

Here is my code:

```
{
    this.state.measure.map((data, index) => {
        let time = data.duration
        const totalTime = time.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.time) - parseFloat(b.time))
        console.log(totalTime)
    })
}
```

If I console.log(time) I receive 15:00, 12:00, 50:00, 15:10 that is the data that I want to sort, but first I need to convert to numbers using parseFloat() and later use to order, anyway, this is not the problem.
Looks like that the `sort()` is the problem in my code.
This is my JSON.

```
{
  "measures": [
    {
      "_id": "5fb56d5e734b7e04b9c97c9d",
      "creationDate": "18/11/2020",
      "startTime": "10:00",
      "duration": "15:00",
      "voltage": "220V",
      "avgPower": "34W",
      "maxPower": "7200W",
      "WaterConsumption": "30",
      "avgTemperature": "42",
      "maxTemperature": "48",
      "shower": "5fb56ce7734b7e04b9c97c9b",
      "__v": 0,
      "id": "5fb56d5e734b7e04b9c97c9d"
    },
  ]
}
```

I have three objects like this one and I just want to order them from the smaller to the largest one.

I tried to change the code to

```
{this.state.measure.map((data, index)=> {
    let time = parseFloat(data.duration)
    console.log(time)
})}
```

Now I receive 15, 12, 50, 17.1

Comment: The duration is a string, not an array, so you cannot sort it.

Comment: Yeah, but I used parseFloat() to convert to numbers.

Comment: That doesn't matter. You can't sort a string. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What do you want to sort from it?

Comment: Sorting a string would be like `kitten` to `eikntt` :-?

Comment: I didn't knew it. I'm receiving three numbers from the duration, the numbers 15, 12, 50 and 17.1. And I want to order them form the smaller to the larger. Like 12, 15, 17.1, 50

Comment: the time refer to duration. and is string. so you try to sort letters in duration string.

Comment: What is `this.state.measure`? Is it the `measures` array from the JSON, converted to a JS array?

Comment: I'm guessing OP wants to sort measure by duration? In which case it needs `this.state.measures.sort()` .... ?

Comment: and he call variable totalTime so maybe reduce.

Comment: @RafaeldeFreitas Yes. Look my update in the question. i just want to order the numbers.

Comment: Sorting measures by duration: `measures.sort((measure1, measure2) => measure1.duration.localeCompare(measure2.duration))` There is no need to parse the duration.

Comment: If you really want to convert the duration string to a number, then you can convert it to minutes, using this function: `function d2m(d) { return +d.substring(0, 2) * 60 + +d.substring(3, 5); }` Using this function, the sort would look like this: `measures.sort((measure1, measure2) => d2m(measure1.duration) - d2m(measure2.duration))`

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

as the time format is in string and have : before using parseFloat
Just do time.split(':').join('.')

```
this.state.measure.map((data, index) => {
        let time = data.duration
        const totalTime = time.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.time.split(':').join('.') )- parseFloat(b.time.split(':').join('.')))
        console.log(totalTime)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should sort the `measures` array instead.

```
this.state.measure.sort((a,b)=>{
   const [m, s] = a.time.split(":").map(Number), [m2, s2] = b.time.split(":").map(Number);
   return m * 60 + s - (m2 * 60 + s2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong then you are wanting something like this-

```js
const data = {
  "measures": [
    {
      "_id": "5fbaaa",
      "duration": "15:00",
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fbbdd",
      "duration": "12:20",
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fbbbb",
      "duration": "12:00",
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fbccc",
      "duration": "25:30",
    },
  ]
};

const inMin = (duration) => {
  const [hour, min] = duration.split(':');
  return hour * 60 + min * 1;
}

data.measures.sort((a, b) => {
  return inMin(b.duration) - inMin(a.duration);
});

console.log(data);
```

Here I've shortened your data structure and assume your duration in `HH:mm` format and convert the duration in minute and sorting in `desc` order.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so sounds like you want to sort the array. For that, you should use the `Array.sort` method instead of `Array.map`.

The following piece of code will sort the array comparing `duration` values. [String.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) is a handy function for that, since it already converts the date for you.

```js
this.state.measures.sort((a,b) => a.duration.localeCompare(b.duration))
```

Comment: This one is getting close. But when I change "map" to sort, says: "Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.measures.sort'), I tried to debug in parts, and when I change from map to sort automatically crash. I tried to create an empty array and push the values to there, but it creates a new array for each of the numbers.